# How to naturally say "I did X when I should have done Y"

Tags: english-to-japanese

If I want to say, for example"

> I used the "write" kanji when I should have used the "draw" kanji.

Do I say it like this, or is there a better way?

> 「描く」の漢字を使ったほうがいい時、「書く」の漢字を使ってしまいました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ところ instead of とき.

- 「描く」の漢字を使ったほうがいい**ところで**、「書く」の漢字を使ってしまいました。
- 「描く」の字を使うべき**ところで**「書く」の方を使ってしまいました。